# lua socket receive string of unknown length

Tags: python, sockets, lua, client

I have a socket server which listens for commands and responds to them. The responses are not always of the same length. In python the following code runs fine, even if the response from the server is smaller than 1024 Bytes.

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(("localhost", 9999))
sock.sendall(bytes("command\n", 'utf-8'))
print(sock.recv(1024))
```

Now I want to translate this to an equivalent lua code. This is my attempt:

```
socket = require("socket")
sock = socket.connect("localhost", 9999)
sock:send("command\n")
s, status, partial = sock:receive(1024)
print(s)
```

Unfortunately, the receive call blocks, if there are less than 1024 Bytes sent. How does the python client find out that the transmission is over and why does the lua client still wait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua receive is blocking, while python recv is non-blocking if there is at least 1 byte. The underlying tcp protocol does not guarantee that more than 1 byte is read. So it's only luck, if you receive the whole response in python. On the other side, Lua expects exactly 1024 bytes and waits until the server has send 1024 or the socket is closed.

TCP is a streaming protocol. You need some kind of length indicator or end-of-message mark, like newline, you can write in lua:

```
s = sock:receive('*l')
```

Comment: which means, I have to change the response in the server, right?